# Find Explicit Formula for Power Series

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, power-series

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left({(-1)^{n}}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)$

**Step 1:**

I took derivative of the power series and got

$(-1)^n\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left({x^n}\right)$

The explicit formula would be $(-1)^n$ $\frac{1}{1-x}$

**Step 2:**

I integrated the power series back to the original form and integrated the explicit formula as well

The explicit formula I got was $-(-1)^n$ ln(|1-x|)

I believe this is incorrect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you take the $(-1)^n$ outside of the summation!?  (but other than that, it looks fine)

Comment: I thought since n is a constant, I could do that

Comment: If $n$ were constant (with respect to the summation) then you may as well take everything outside the summation!

Comment: $n$ is not a constant, $(-1)^n$ depends on summation index ;)

Comment: Its is well-known this series is the Taylor's series for $\ln(1+x)$.

Comment: Let’s put it a different way. What does $n$ stand for in the explicit formula that you got for the derivative?

Comment: $n$ is the variable for the summation.  What you've done is as wrong as the following: $$\int \sin(t)~\mathrm dt=\sin(t)\int~\mathrm dt=(t+C)\sin(t)$$which is clearly wrong.

Comment: An example $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^n\cdot 2\cdot x\cdot x^n$$ the constants with respect of $n$ are $2, x$ but not $(-1)^n$ and $x^n$, so by a series property we can write $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^n\cdot 2\cdot x\cdot x^n=2\cdot x\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^n x^n$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments say:

(-1)^n depends on the index so it cannot be taken outside the summation.